# Is there a way in parboiled2 to subclass so that you can, ie accept multiple syntaxes (PowerShell-style, bash/sh-style, Cisco-style)?

Tags: scala, command-line-interface, parboiled, parboiled2

Warning I am new to `parboiled2`.

I would like to be able to write my CLI in a way that is somewhat agnostic of the syntax involved. It will always have the same shape, a triplet of:

```
case class Command(command: String, modifiers: Seq[String] = Nil, arguments: Seq[String] = Nil)
```

I would like to take this further to, perhaps subclass this or subclass its parser, or otherwise extend to achieve the ability to have:

```
case class CreateDogCommand(cmd: String, mods: Seq[String], args: Seq[String])
```

accept any of:

- `Create-Dog -Feet 4 -Name Fido -Walks Daily /Home/Dogs`
- `create_dog -f 4 --name Fido ~/Dogs`
- `Dog.Create Feet=4, Name=Fido, Walks=Daily in /Home/Dogs`

just as an example. I am **not asking for the particulars at all here**; what I am asking is how I might tackle this from the get-go.

I see at least two or three approaches.

1. Leave the existing `CommandParser` as is, and write command-specific parsers for each command-syntax permutation
2. Leave the existing but write command-specific, syntax-neutral parsers for each command so that any syntax may be used as long as it is used across the board (but how would I do this?)
3. Write a `CommandParser` per syntax.

Current `CommandParser` is mostly "inspired" from other open source:

```
object CommandParser {

  case class Command(command: String, modifiers: Seq[String] = Nil, arguments: Seq[String] = Nil)

}

trait CommandParser extends Parser {

  import CommandParser._

  val WhiteSpaceChar = CharPredicate(" \n\r\t\f")

  def CommandEntry: Rule1[Command] =
    rule { commandName ~ OptionalSpace ~ modifiers ~ OptionalSpace ~ arguments ~ EOI ~> Command }

  def commandName = rule { capture(oneOrMore(AlphaNum | '-')) ~> (_.toString.replace(" ", "")) }

  def modifiers = rule { zeroOrMore(ch('-') ~ capture(AlphaNumericString)).separatedBy(WhiteSpace) }

  def arguments = rule { zeroOrMore(capture(CharacterString)).separatedBy(WhiteSpace) }

  def AlphaNumericString = rule { oneOrMore(AlphaNum) }

  def CharacterString = rule { oneOrMore(Visible) }

  def WhiteSpace = rule { zeroOrMore(WhiteSpaceChar) }

  def OptionalSpace = rule { optional(ch(' ')) }

}
```

So I was thinking that perhaps I should extend the `CommandParser` or just tack onto waht I ahve